# how do i overwrite documents in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have an excel document on sharepoint where the users update the document everyday, how do i automate overwriting this document every week to a new document which is blank to facilitate the following week ?

Comment: Please ask a separate question about archiving the document.

Answer (score 0):

Create PowerShell script to upload the file to library and schedule it to run weekly.

PowerShell script demo:

```
# Set a few variables
$file = "C:\Lee\template.xlsx"
$TTNwebUrl = "http://sp"
$library = "MyDoc"
$overWriteExisting = $True #or add new version if versioning enabled

# do a little SharePoint setup
$web = Get-SPWeb $TTNwebUrl
$files = $web.GetFolder($library).Files
$fileNameForLibrary = $file.Substring($file.LastIndexOf("\")+1) 

# read the file
$data = Get-ChildItem $file

# add any needed metadata
#$metadata = @{ "Field" = "value"; "FieldB" = "valueB" }
$metadata = @{}

# or if no metadata needed: $metadata = @{}

# do the upload (the following is one line)
$newfile = $files.Add($library + "/" + $fileNameForLibrary, $data.OpenRead(), $metadata, $overWriteExisting)
```

[How to Automate PowerShell Scripts with Task Scheduler](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/)